# How to advance focus automatically when each input reaches maxlength

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, usability

In order to increase usability for a credit card form I'm building, I want the browser to move the focus to the next input once the user has typed in the characters allowed in the `maxlength` attribute of the `input`.

I've accomplished this with three input fields at present but in a very clunky, not scaleable way. See below code.

What I would like to do is script the following:

> If an input with the class autotab has reached it maxlength, move the focus to the next closest input of any class. Additionally (what I have not yet accomplished in my code below) if the value of an input with the class autotab is empty/null, and the backspace/delete key is pressed, the focus should move to the previous closest input of any class`

My goal is to get away from the dependency on writing variables for specific fields and automate this process a bit.

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {

    var CCCardFill = 0;
    var CCExpMonthFill = 0;
    var CCExpYearFill = 0;  

    var CCCardMax = 16;
    var CCExpMonthMax =  2;
    var CCExpYearMax =  4;

   $( "input" ).keyup(function() {
      var CCCardFill = $(".CCCard").val().length;
      var CCExpMonthFill = $(".CCExpMonth").val().length;
      var CCExpYearFill = $(".CCExpYear").val().length;

      if (CCCardFill >= CCCardMax) {
        $(".CCExpMonth").focus();
      }
      if (CCExpMonthFill >= CCExpMonthMax) {
        $(".CCExpYear").focus();
      }
      if (CCExpYearFill >= CCExpYearMax) {
        $(".CCName").focus();
      }

  });

  });
```

Functioning codepen here: http://codepen.io/jeremypbeasley/pen/BoJVRW

Comment: As a user of the Web, I am appalled enough to ask how this improves usability.  In particular, how will your users cope with mistyping the last digit of their credit card numbers?

Comment: It's modeled after LukeW's (Mr. Usability himself) single input credit card form. http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1667 We tested the form that resulted from the answers below against Luke's and a conventional "tab to advance focus" field and it out performed exponentially both in speed and user satisfaction.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `maxLength` and `value.length` properties. When it reaches the max length, you can simply focus the next item using `next().focus()`.

```
$( "input[maxlength]" ).keyup(function() {
    var maxLen = this.maxLength;
    var currentLen = this.value.length;

    if (maxLen === currentLen)
    {
        $(this).next().focus(); 
    } 
});
```

Here is the [working JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/er5kLfka/).

In case if there are other HTML elements between your `input`s, you can use `nextAll("input").first()` to get the **closest element matching the selector after this one**:

```
$(this).nextAll("input").first().focus();
```

[Another one JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/er5kLfka/2/).

Comment: How about `>=` instead of `===` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre Can `value.length` be more than `maxLength`?

Comment: Man... so helpful. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can simply do:

```
$(this).next("input").focus();
```

To replace your `.focus()` items. This will move to the next `input` element in the DOM from the current element you are on.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("input").keyup(function() {
  var value = $(this).val().length;
  var max = $(this).attr('maxlength')
  console.log(value);
  console.log(max);
  if (value == max) {
    console.log('equal');
    $("input").next().focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' maxlength='10'>
<input type='text' maxlength='10'>
```

Try getting the attr maxlength and compare it to the val().length if equal focus next input

Comment: how will you reach the maxlength if it does not have maxlength attribute?

Comment: How about more specific selector ? Comparing length with `null` or `undefined` does not make sense to me!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
function autotab(current,to){
    if (current.getAttribute && 
      current.value.length==current.getAttribute("maxlength")) {
        to.focus() 
        }
}
</script>

<b>Enter your phone number ex (1-888-555-1234):</b>
<form name="telephone">
<input type="text" name="phone0" 
    size=2 onKeyup="autotab(this, document.telephone.phone1)" maxlength=1>- 
<input type="text" name="phone1" 
    size=4 onKeyup="autotab(this, document.telephone.phone2)" maxlength=3>- 
<input type="text" name="phone2" 
    size=4 onKeyup="autotab(this, document.telephone.phone3)" maxlength=3>- 
<input type="text" name="phone3" size=5 maxlength=4>
</form>
```

Here is how I would accomplish this. Each element uses the onKeyup event to call the autotab function sending its own object and the object of the following element to focus on then testing for maxlength.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at the input that had the event triggered on. `this` within event handler is the element wanted

```
var $inputs = $( "input" )

$inputs.keyup(function() {
   var $input = $(this), max = $input.attr('maxlength');
   if(max){
      max = parseInt(max,10);
      if(this.value && this.value.length == max){
           $inputs( $inputs.index(this) +1).focus()
      }
   }

})
```